# Formatting Lat/Long via an exiftool format file

Tags: format, exiftool

I used

```
exiftool -c "%.6f" -p ~/bin/gpx.fmt (dir) > (file).gpx
```

to create a GPX file for all ages in the directory.

I copied ~/bin/gpx.fmt from [GitHub](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/blob/master/fmt_files/gpx.fmt)

With the syntax I used, `-c` is ignored and I get 13 decimal places.  I doubt any GPS device exists with accuracy of a centimeter (seven decimal places), so I'd like to know how to modify the format file to be more reasonable.

See also https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/issues/156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been educated by the comments on the GitHub issue.

By removing the `#` from `$latitude#` and `$longitude#`, the coordformat is no longer ignored.